# How to repair my LVM volume which fails with "device not found"?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, lvm

On the next boot after an fairly standard upgrade on my arch linux box, the system failed to boot and stopped in maintenance mode ; I found out that if I commented out in /etc/fstab the lvm partition that I have on a secondary disk (my root and home are not in LVM) it accepted to boot.

Now it runs OK but I can't access the data on this partition, and the necessary device doesn't get created. The various scan commands of LVM tell me that : **"WARNING: Device for PV WbbZgi-PEpk-mWNz-faCX-IT1n-Vrsd-wFoGOP not found or rejected by a filter."** I haven't changed any configuration and I don't have any filter in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf. Here are some infos I think are relevant :

```
[root@bureau64 ~]# cat /etc/fstab
# /dev/sdb3
UUID=a2b6fa8e-1255-4563-b126-153c5a9178b5   /           btrfs       rw,noatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/  0 0
# /dev/sdb4
UUID=a8c42099-3ec2-4bb9-b0ea-a126167523ef   /home       btrfs       rw,noatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/  0 0
# /dev/sdb1
UUID=bc6e027d-ae37-419e-b394-02d4674e693f   /boot       ext2        rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl   0 2
# /dev/sdb2
UUID=839a15de-bd4d-47a1-9727-6a9d394d741a   none        swap        defaults    0 0
## THE ONE I HAD TO COMMENT :
#/dev/VGroupe0/data             /data       ext4        rw,data=ordered 0 2

[root@bureau64 ~]# ls /dev/VGroupe0
ls: impossible d'accéder à '/dev/VGroupe0': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

[root@bureau64 ~]# pvscan 
  WARNING: Device for PV WbbZgi-PEpk-mWNz-faCX-IT1n-Vrsd-wFoGOP not found or rejected by a filter.
  PV /dev/sda4   VG VGroupe0        lvm2 [217,46 GiB / 168,00 MiB free]
  PV [unknown]   VG VGroupe0        lvm2 [107,57 GiB / 77,57 GiB free]
  Total: 2 [<325,04 GiB] / in use: 2 [<325,04 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

[root@bureau64 ~]# lvscan 
  WARNING: Device for PV WbbZgi-PEpk-mWNz-faCX-IT1n-Vrsd-wFoGOP not found or rejected by a filter.
  inactive          '/dev/VGroupe0/root' [25,00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/VGroupe0/home' [5,00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/VGroupe0/data' [<217,30 GiB] inherit

[root@bureau64 ~]# blkid 
/dev/sda1: UUID="0C60E75260E740D6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c169c169-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="395e11a4-6841-455c-b2f6-ff84d8d73f49" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="c169c169-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="swap" UUID="bf964fa7-8690-4111-89d1-7cbbc0a1df43" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c169c169-03"
/dev/sda4: UUID="CF3ZqC-JNaF-BMlE-uCT8-Mv0E-dfPm-a2vmea" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="c169c169-04"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="bc6e027d-ae37-419e-b394-02d4674e693f" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="a294f4fa-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="839a15de-bd4d-47a1-9727-6a9d394d741a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a294f4fa-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="a2b6fa8e-1255-4563-b126-153c5a9178b5" UUID_SUB="22f83bf4-0c48-44ad-b016-7edf820c365e" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="a294f4fa-03"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="a8c42099-3ec2-4bb9-b0ea-a126167523ef" UUID_SUB="ae03aa3d-8823-47ea-83b2-53f584e03e59" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="a294f4fa-04"
```

I don't exactly remember the configuration of my LVM partitions, the volumes 'root' and 'home' were from a previous install and I don't care about them, but I care quite a lot about 'data'. How can I fix this issue and mount my partition again ?

Comment: Does your system only have two hard drives?

Comment: Yes : one HD and one SSD that I installed later, hence the old root and home in the LVM volume.

Answer (score 1):

vgreduce --removemissing --force centos

(in my case the centos was the VG name replace with your respective VG name)

Comment: Run this with care, as vgreduce with --force can be potential dangerous and cause data loss in some situations.

Comment: This doesn't help if the vg doesn't exist, and just pv does.